# Pandas Dataframe: How to check if a column contains continues integers, and if not, how to add and fill 0

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Assume we have a dataframe like this:

```
Order Value
1     10
2     3
3     5
5     34
7     23
```

Is there a way to test if a column (In this case 'Order') contains continues integers. And if it doesn't, is there a way to fill in the missing row with corresponding integer and set other column(In this case 'Value') with 0, or other specific value?

Like in the case above, there should be two rows be added (4,0), and(6,0)

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) after setting `Order` as index. With the `fill_value` argument you can choose which value will be used for filling in new rows.

```
df.set_index('Order').reindex(pd.RangeIndex(df.Order.min(), df.Order.max()+1), fill_value=0).reset_index()
```

Out:

```
   Order  Value
0      1     10
1      2      3
2      3      5
3      4      0
4      5     34
5      6      0
6      7     23
```